# how to transform an array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects of people into a new object with its property names arranged by age each in a separate array.

#### Example 1

Input:

```
groupAdultsByAgeRange([{name: "Henry", age: 9}, {name: "John", age: 20}])
```

Result:

```
{ '20 and younger': [ { name: 'John', age: 20 } ] }
```

#### Example 2

Input:

```
groupAdultsByAgeRange([{name: "Anna", age: 31}, {name: "John", age: 32}, {name: "Hank", age: 60}])
```

Result:

```
{ 
  '31-40': [ { name: 'Anna', age: 31 }, { name: 'John', age: 32 } ],
  '51 and older': [ { name: 'Hank', age: 60 } ] 
}
```

If the age range is not in the input than it should not be part of the output. For example if the input does not have people with age 51 than the object should not contain property of '51 and older'. and if input us empty array than output should be an empty object.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Why didn't that work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show an attempt as a [mcve]. Also, the requirements are a bit unclear to me. Why is the cutoff 20 in the first case (John is 20 but wasn't included in "20 and under" surprisingly...) but 31-40 and 51 in the second case? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be very useful in this case. Try to combine it with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) you can do something like this

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const array = [{name: "Anna", age: 31}, {name: "John", age: 32}, {name: "Hank", age: 60}];

function ageToRange(obj) {
  const age = obj.age;
  if (age <= 20) {
    return '20 and younger';
  } 
  if (age > 30 && age <= 40) {
    return '31-40'
  }
  if (age > 50) {
    return '51 and older';
  }
}

const result = _.groupBy(array, ageToRange)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do with native Javascript :

```js
//example 1
  let people1 = [{name: "Henry", age: 9}, {name: "John", age: 20}]
  let younger_and_equal_20 = []
  people1.forEach(e => {
   if(e.age>=20){
    younger_and_equal_20.push(e)
   }
  }); 
  console.log({"20 and younger": younger_and_equal_20})

  //example 2
  let people2 = [{name: "Anna", age: 31}, {name: "John", age: 32}, {name: "Hank", age: 60}]
  let data = {
   "31-40" : [],
   "51 and older" : []
  }
  people2.forEach(e => {
   if(e.age>30 && e.age<=40){
    data["31-40"].push(e)
   }
   else if(e.age>50){
    data["51 and older"].push(e)
   }
  });
  console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let result = {}

    function groupAdultsByAgeRange(people) {
        // An array of object which represents people who are 20 or younger
        const ageGroup = people.filter(person => person.age <= 20)

        // Only add array to the object key if it's not empty
        if (ageGroup.length > 0) {
            result["20 and younger"] = ageGroup
        }

        return result;
    }
```